# Node pattern I see, but do not understand why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

When going through so projects I have seen people do this pattern in module exports in this format:

```
var utils = require('../lib/bhalnhahaha'); 
module.exports = utils;
```

I am just not sure why they would not:

```
var whatever = require('../lib/bhalnhahaha');
```

require utils in the file instead of using the exports?

Comment: I imagine people do this to add methods to modules as they develop their application and need to extend the functionality of the library. So imagine I wanted to add a function to `utils` so I can use it elsewhere that I already required utils, something like: `utils.myNewFunction = function () { return utils.doSomething() + utils.doSomethingElse() }` then I don't have to require an additional function, it just gets attached to utils before it is exported and could use it wherever utils is already being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think of two reasons for doing this:

```
var utils = require('../lib/bhalnhahaha'); 

// ... other code here

module.exports = utils;
```

1. You're augmenting or extending the `utils` object and adding your own additional methods to it and you want to export the augmented `utils` object.
2. There some side affect in the "other code here" that is somehow useful to whatever this module is doing and you want both that side affect (perhaps even initializing something in the `utils` object or doing something else in the local environment).

Otherwise, it's better to just let the caller import `utils` directly and not create an unnecessary dependency on your module.

A more specific answer can only be provided by showing us an actual example of code doing this and then we can see what it is actually doing that is of use.

Comment: yes it really does and I do believe they are extending the utils thanks for this answer it helps clear up how you can augment the  utils obj. here is the link to the src code and all the util functions. Its for the google maps react heat-map. Building a Covid-19 heat map for the community. Thanks!   Code LINK = https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/tree/master/src/utils

Comment: @JoshuaAguilar - You can indicate to the community that your question has been answered by clicking the checkmark to the left of this answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.